# ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tiny-tds

In my Rails 3.1 application (runs on Ubuntu 11.10) , I am using tiny-tds, sqlserver active record adapter. My default database is mysql but I also connect to SqlServer 2005 for business logic. When I connect to sql server 2005 and query the database I get an error which says "ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)" How can I solve this problem ?

By the way my development machine is Mac Os X lion and there isn't any problem.